# ChartJS : It's not showing in html on Django

Tags: python, html, django, chart.js

I will plot horizontal bar chart in html but it's not showing. I send 2 variable from views.py are `{{top5StockCode}}` and `{{top5TotalSales}}`.
The values of `{{top5StockCode}}` that views.py sent is

> ['23166', '21108', '85123A', '48185', '22470']

and `{{top5TotalSales}}`

> [2671740, 227322, 171770, 158120, 143808].

This is my code in html file.

```
<div class="top5">
    <p class="topicTop5">Top 5 Selling Products</p>
    <canvas id="top5"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var top5 = document.getElementById('top5').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(top5, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: {{top5StockCode}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Top 5 selling products ',
                backgroundColor: '#CE3B21',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: {{top5TotalSales}}
            }]
        },
        options: {   
            legend: { 
                display: false
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                         beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm so confused why it's not showing graph. Please help me. Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjzo7v63/) using your data.

So probably you need to write the array in the template as json like `{{ top5StockCode|safe }}` and `{{top5TotalSales|safe}}`

so your final code should be:

```
<div class="top5">
    <p class="topicTop5">Top 5 Selling Products</p>
    <canvas id="top5"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var top5 = document.getElementById('top5').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(top5, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: {{top5StockCode|safe}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Top 5 selling products ',
                backgroundColor: '#CE3B21',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: {{top5TotalSales|safe}}
            }]
        },
        options: {   
            legend: { 
                display: false
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                         beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to use variable that view.py sent because the value on graph have to change when I filter data. Thank for your reccomend.

Comment: @atjab second example uses the variables sent by view

Comment: Oh!!! thank you so much. It's worked. I solved this problem many times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include the library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

**Try This code**

```html
<div class="top5">
    <p class="topicTop5">Top 5 Selling Products</p>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <canvas id="top5"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var top5 = document.getElementById('top5').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(top5, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: {{top5StockCode|safe}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Top 5 selling products ',
                backgroundColor: '#CE3B21',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: {{top5TotalSales|safe}}
            }]
        },
        options: {   
            legend: { 
                display: false
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                         beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```